# Use composer to require only 1 file?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it possible to require only 1 file from a composer package?

I need only 1 or few files from a package and it would be pointless to require the whole package which consist of hundred of files when i would use only a few.

Is it possible to do this via composer?

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to include specific files in the current package with the [`files` autoloading strategy](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files):

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "path/to/my/file.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

If you need to require specific files from a package you installed with composer, this is not possible. Not really needed either, as the files are not loaded into memory unless you use them in your code.

More about files and other autoloading stragegies can be found in [the composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).

Comment: No, i think you did not understand me well....
lets say i am working on a project and there is a package which contain files: `a.php`, `b.php`, `c.php` and `d.php`. if i require the package in my composer  all the files a b c and d will be downloaded to my vendor directory. but i only need file `a.php`. is there a way to require only the `a.php` file without having the need to download b c and d to my vendor dir?

Comment: Read my second sentence. No, it's not possible.

Comment: this answer suggests otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44849091/5240159

Comment: @majick features are added to composer over time (either directly or with third party plugins).

Comment: yes just wanted to note on it is possible now if anyone was looking for this (as I was)