# Is it possible to get /dist only in Composer?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php, bower

I'd like to use composer for managing my front-end dependencies as well.
Unfortunately, using `"bower-asset/bootstrap": "dev-master"` or `"twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master"` brings more than 80 MB of code, while I need only /dist/ from the whole bootstrap folder.

Is it possible to add only /dist/ of bootstrap to my application using dependency manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore files with the composer fxp-asset plugin.

For instance, if want only the **dist** folder of bootstrap, add these lines in your composer.json :

```
 "config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "fxp-asset":{
        "ignore-files": {
            "bower-asset/bootstrap": [
                "!dist",
                "*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Composer cannot influence what is in the packages you download. Especially if you depend on branches (hint: don't do it), basically the only thing Composer does is clone that repository. This adds up to probably the amount of data you see.

You may try to influence what Composer downloads by adding `--prefer-dist` to the update command (you may need to delete the vendor folder before you update), but if Composer is unable to locate a source for a ZIP download, it will still clone the repo.

Comment: at least this reduces size of `twbs/composer` directory from 80 to 10 MB. I'll investigate this more. If no other options will be available, this is going to be the solution.