# TypeRocket: php script stops running when function is called via Controller

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to utilize [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) in typerocket but I'm having trouble when I try to use its API in a `Controller`.

I have the the following routes (in `routes.php`):

```
tr_route()->get()->match('/exp-get/')->do('experiment@Customer');
tr_route()->get()->match('/exp-get2/')->do(function() {

  require_once TR_PATH . '/vendor/firephp/firephp-core/lib/FirePHPCore/fb.php';

    echo 'before';
    fb('Hello World!', FirePHP::INFO);
    echo 'after';

});
```

the `CustomerController` contains:

```
public function experiment() {

require_once TR_PATH . '/vendor/firephp/firephp-core/lib/FirePHPCore/fb.php';
echo 'before';
fb('Hello World!', FirePHP::INFO);
echo 'after';

}
```

Now, when I call https://dummy-domain.org/exp-get2/ everything runs as expected, but however, when I call https://dummy-domain.org/exp-get/ only '*before*' is `echo`ed (or printed) but not the rest! Unfortunately no errors are logged even though I've configured php logging. What might be the reason for this and why isn't the error logged if there is any error?

Additionally, I'm having the issue that I need to explicitly require_once `fb.php` although FirePHP should be autoloaded, as outside of the `do` related functions I can use the FirePHP API without having to do this! Isn't the autoload working here?

Note: I'm using the lastest TypeRocket version.

Comment: Hey Osman,

Have you tried installing FirePHP using composer?

composer require firephp/firephp-core

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention that it is installed via composer. Yet it does not work and I need to fetch fb.php explicitly.. Anyhow, why isn't the error logged in all cases?

Comment: but I know it gets autloaded outside of the route callback functions

Comment: Maybe try loading the file via composer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361360/use-composer-to-require-only-1-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By further debugging I noticed that the php engine was complaining about that a`FirePHP` class was not found which is used inside the `fb` function. As a result I just had to put this statement on top of the class which contains that `experiment` method:

```
use \FirePHP;
```

those `require_once TR_PATH . '/vendor/firephp/firephp-core/lib/FirePHPCore/fb.php';` lines are unnecessary since the autoloader handels that stuff already.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58242127/7449839) led me to the right direction.