# How to autoload a class inside the composer file and run a script?

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, autoload

I'm on Drupal 9.3.x trying to add a script to run with composer, following [this guide](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/add-composer-script-your-module-or-theme)

I've tried either to add the *autoload* and *script* part to the drupal project `composer.json` file

```json
{
    "name": "drupal/d9-starter-kit",
    "description": "Project template for D9 starter kit",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "Drupal\\d9_starter_kit\\Starter.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "doStart": [
            "Drupal\\d9_starter_kit\\Starter::doStart"
        ]
    }, 
    // require, extra, etc...
}
```

or to create a `composer.json` inside the custom module I've made

```json
{
    "name": "drupal/d9_starter_kit",
    "type": "drupal-custom-module",
    "description": "a module to script the start",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My name",
            "email": "mymail@mail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
   "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src\\Starter.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "doStart": [
            "Drupal\\d9_starter_kit\\Starter::doStart"
        ]
    }
}
```

and include that to the project composer file, according the [the guide on Drupal site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/managing-dependencies-for-a-custom-project)

The path of the Start class is `web/modules/custom/d9_starter_kit/src/Starter.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\d9_starter_kit;

class Starter {
  public static function doStart() {
    print('test');
    // TODO
  }
}
```

I've tried various other syntax for the *autoload* part - e.g. `d9_starter_kit\\Starter.php` - but none works.

I get the following error

> Could not scan for classes inside "Drupal\d9_starter_kit\Starter.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

> Class Drupal\d9_starter_kit\Starter is not autoloadable, can not call doStart script

What is the correct way to autoload the class and run a script? The objective of the latter is the same of the guide, copy, rename and edit some files in order of automate the "start up" of a custom project template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use composer to require only 1 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361360/use-composer-to-require-only-1-file)

Comment: Unfortunately not: if I put `"files": [
            "web/modules/custom/d9_starter_kit/src/Starter.php"]` inside the _project_ composer.json I still get the error "Class Drupal\d9_starter_kit\Starter is not autoloadable, can not call doStart script". Same if I put `"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Starter.php"
        ]
    },`  and run from the module composer.json